# problem with color and symbol replacement codes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I liked the color selection part of a site and I wanted to use it by pulling the codes, but I can't click the buttons I couldn't understand why it wasn't working. The codes are attached. Does anyone know what the problem is?

https://output.jsbin.com/heduhareye

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link as="script" href="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/insideIframe.js" rel="preload">
    <script src="https://fast.wistia.net/assets/external/E-v1.js" async=""></script>
    <script src="https://script.crazyegg.com/pages/scripts/0030/3951.js?454398" async="" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://www.autexglobal.com/production/js/main.js?m=1629757511"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    window.whenDefined(window, 'dataLayer', function () {
        window.dataLayer.push({"event":"pageLoad","page":"3D Tiles","country":"United States"});
    });
//]]></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.autexglobal.com/production/css/main.css?m=1629757511">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.autexglobal.com/production/css/main.css?1">
</head>

<body>
    <section class="c-content-block c-content-block--background c-content-block--horizontal-padding c-content-block--no-padding-mobile-only">
        <div id="js-colour-picker">
            <div class="c-colour-picker">
                <div class="c-colour-picker__gallery null">
                    <div>
                        <div class="c-colour-picker__gallery--image" style="display: block; opacity: 1;"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/3DTiles/StyleSelector/IA-3D-Tiles-S-5__FillWzE2MDAsNjUwXQ.37-BrilliantOrange-1600x650.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="c-colour-picker__picker">
                        <h3 class="c-colour-picker__title">3D Tiles color and style selector</h3>
                        <div class="c-colour-picker__options">
                            <div class="c-colour-picker__section c-colour-picker__section--colours">
                                <div class="c-colour-picker__current">
                                    <div class="c-colour-picker__current-swatch"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Brilliant-Orange__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt="Brilliant Orange"><a href="/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Brilliant-Orange.jpg" class="c-download" download=""><svg width="20" height="19" viewBox="0 0 20 19" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path fill-rule="nonzero" d="M17 8l-1.41-1.41L11 11.17V0H9v11.17L4.42 6.58 3 8l7 7z"></path>
                                                <path d="M0 17h20v2H0z"></path>
                                            </svg></a></div>
                                    <h4 class="c-colour-picker__current-title">Brilliant Orange</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="c-colour-picker__swatches">
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker c-colour-swatch--active" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Brilliant-Orange__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Blazing-Red__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Blush__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Stately__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Electric-Blue__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Stonewash__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Porcelain__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Avocado__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Granny-Smith__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Bark__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Fawn__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Noir__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Charcoal__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Silver__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/2-Colour-Swatches/Civic__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="c-colour-picker__section c-colour-picker__section--styles">
                                <div class="c-colour-picker__current">
                                    <div class="c-colour-picker__current-swatch"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/1-Style-Thumbnails/Style_S-5__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.37.png" alt="S-5.37"><a href="/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/1-Style-Thumbnails/Style_S-5.37.png" class="c-download" download="S-5.37"><svg width="20" height="19" viewBox="0 0 20 19" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path fill-rule="nonzero" d="M17 8l-1.41-1.41L11 11.17V0H9v11.17L4.42 6.58 3 8l7 7z"></path>
                                                <path d="M0 17h20v2H0z"></path>
                                            </svg></a></div>
                                    <h4 class="c-colour-picker__current-title">S-5.37</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="c-colour-picker__swatches">
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--style c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/1-Style-Thumbnails/Style_S-5__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.26.png" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--style c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/1-Style-Thumbnails/Style_S-5__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.34.png" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--style c-colour-swatch--picker c-colour-swatch--active" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/1-Style-Thumbnails/Style_S-5__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.37.png" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--style c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/1-Style-Thumbnails/Style_S-5__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.46.png" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--style c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/1-Style-Thumbnails/Style_S-5__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.53.png" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--style c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/1-Style-Thumbnails/Style_S-5__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.28.png" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--style c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/1-Style-Thumbnails/Style_S-5__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.32.png" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="c-colour-swatch c-colour-swatch--style c-colour-swatch--picker" role="button" tabindex="0">
                                        <div class="c-colour-swatch__inner"><img src="https://www.autexglobal.com/assets/Autex-Acoustics-Website/Products/1-Style-Thumbnails/Style_S-5__FillWzEzMCwxMzBd.50.png" alt=""></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to see the original version of the site, you can reach

[link](https://www.autexglobal.com/us/autex-acoustics/acoustic-solutions/3d-tiles/) by clicking here.

Comment: Have you just copy pasted from the original? First I can see you get an error with `window.whenDefined` second where is the js code that should be triggered when you click the color?

Comment: I pulled the css and js codes related to the code on the page, it may be missing, I left the original link, can you examine it?

Comment: Well you haven't included the main.js file. Event with this file included their can be many reason why it's not working. Is the code open source or?

Comment: <script type="application/javascript" src="https://www.autexglobal.com/production/js/main.js?m=1629757511"></script>

this add please

Comment: Are you sure the code is open source?

Comment: Like @hevefig916 said, you should include the script below, but what I would preffer you, is to rewrite it by yourself since it looks like it's a work production work and not lincesed for sharing.

Comment: So where can I find a similar study suitable for this css+html codes ready ?

Comment: @hevefig916 Not sure there is anything like this available for free

Comment: very simple actually why not